# Trying to join opentopomap maps together with mkgmap

Tags: garmin

I'm trying to join the georgia contour map and topo map from http://garmin.opentopomap.org/ with mkgmap using

java -jar mkgmap.jar --gmapsupp georgia_contours.img georgia.img

runs with no errors, but end result file has only 166kb data and no map shows.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the `PC` version zip file, which contains a bunch of single garmin img tiles, including contour img tiles. Mkgmap needs all those single img files for merging:

```
java -Xmx3000M -jar mkgmap.jar --show-profiles=1 --gmapsupp 3*.img OpenTopoMap.TYP
```

The file you downloaded is probably the composite file, usually called gmapsupp.img. It would be possible to break this down into single img files, but the zip version should be easier to handle.

Comment: that worked! brilliant!